# AAA quality game UI kit

Tags: gui

I have often come across many websites which provide free/ paid PSD layouts of website UIs for use by web/ graphics developers.
Are there any such sites where one can find PSD layouts of UI kits for games?

Actually I am looking for some AAA quality game UI and menu screen kits - I have something like the ones in Crysis 2 and Crysis 3 in mind.

Comment: I don't quite get it, by AAA you mean "good quality" right, and by PSDs you mean "Photoshop document" right? Also what do websites that have PSDs available have anything to do with websites with UI kits. Unless I completely am misunderstanding the question.

Comment: Luke San Antonio: I'm guessing he asks whether there are websites which provide PSDs of UI layouts, the same way some websites provide PSDs for web layouts. He's looking for UI templates.

Comment: @rootlocus: Yes, exactly.

Comment: You mean [like this](http://www.designshock.com/gaming-cartoon-gui-psd-elements/) [or this](http://www.loadgraphic.com/download-graphic-hud-controls-psd/) [or this (RPG)](http://dribbble.com/shots/893593-Adventure-Game-Mini-RPG-UI-Pack-Free-PSD) (only better)?  That link posted, this isn't a [good question for this site](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) ("Where free assets can be found" clause)

Comment: @bobobobo: I'm sorry; I'll bear that in mind next time.


By the way, I have already come across most of the stuff you linked to. The thing is that what I am looking for is "AAA quality game UI and menu screen kits". Something like the ones that can be produced by Autodesk Scaleform. Of course I don't expect any such functionality from a UI layout; I only want the design (PSDs).


My designing skills aren't great, which is why I am looking for existing stuff. Later I'll tweak them as required. Thanks anyway. :-)

Comment: One of the best UI editors is Autodesk ScaleForm. It is used by most AAA games + over 80% 3d MMORPGs use its prebuilt MMO game UI solution. http://gameware.autodesk.com/scaleform

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this only required [Google-fu](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=game+ui+psd) but I'll answer it

- [Cartoon PSD](http://www.designshock.com/gaming-cartoon-gui-psd-elements/)
- [Basic HUD](http://www.loadgraphic.com/download-graphic-hud-controls-psd/)
- [50 free basic UI elts](http://www.antsmagazine.com/graphics/50-free-ui-elements-in-psd/)
- [Generic dark UI](http://psddd.co/shot/dark-as-hell-ui_640691.html?ref=related)
- [Tutorial on creating your own UI](http://psd.tutsplus.com/tutorials/interface-tutorials/video-game-interface-photoshop/)
- [PSDList site](http://psdlist.com/graphical-user-interface-gui/)

Comment: I have already tried Google and have come across most of the above stuff. But what I am looking for is "AAA quality game UI and menu screen kits". Something like the ones that can be produced by Autodesk Scaleform.
Of course I don't expect any functionality from a UI layout; I only want the design (PSDs).

My designing skills aren't great, which is why I am looking for existing stuff. Later I'll tweak them as required.

Thanks anyway. :-)

Comment: Well, Google is likely the best anyone can do. The "50.." link should give you a nice starting point for creating your own elts.  If you look through the "Tutorial.." link, it's also got other tutorials on the site.